# Разбор данных массива

Tags: php

Есть вот такой массив:

```
stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 8148
        [order_id] => 8129
        [event_id] => 2808
        [event_places] => a:2:{i:0;a:5:{s:1:"p";s:4:"1000";s:1:"t";s:12:"Партер";s:1:"i";s:4:"10:7";s:1:"r";s:2:"10";s:1:"n";s:2:"15";}i:1;a:5:{s:1:"p";s:4:"1000";s:1:"t";s:12:"Партер";s:1:"i";s:4:"10:6";s:1:"r";s:2:"10";s:1:"n";s:2:"16";}}
        [event_date] => 2021-05-29 12:00:00
    )
```

Интересует строка:

```
[event_places] => a:2:{i:0;a:5:{s:1:"p";s:4:"1000";s:1:"t";s:12:"Партер";s:1:"i";s:4:"10:7";s:1:"r";s:2:"10";s:1:"n";s:2:"15";}i:1;a:5:{s:1:"p";s:4:"1000";s:1:"t";s:12:"Партер";s:1:"i";s:4:"10:6";s:1:"r";s:2:"10";s:1:"n";s:2:"16";}}
```

Не пойму как разложить эти данные. Это данные заказа билета, тут находится информация ряда, места и т.д. Но как достать эти данные по отдельности от туда? Так как планируется например сделать сумму всех выкупленных мест.

Comment: Это, так называемая, сериализованная строка. Используйте [unserialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unserialize.php) для десериализации и дальше с массивом работайте

Comment: Решение:  $test = unserialize($stats_order_res);
    echo '<pre>', print_r( $test ), '</pre>';